# Laravel storage link in shared hosting

Tags: laravel, file-upload, storage, hosting

im having problem with setting up storage link on shared hosting.
Because of that I can't upload any image to storage folder in shared hosting

Comment: your best option would be to use `file_put_contents()` to store image in your public directory.

Answer (score 15):

Just create a route and access it once.

```
Route::get('generate', function (){
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::call('storage:link');
    echo 'ok';
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Adrian you're a life saver 

Comment: Where do I put this? In `web.php`? I've done that but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: yes, in routes/web.php. place it there then access the route /generate, you should see 'ok'. if it's not working there is other problem..

Answer (score 13):

1. Remove storage folder in public_html/public/storage if you perfomed storage:link in local
2. then Create a php file for example mysymlink.php in public_html folder
3. Add below code to mysymlink.php file

```
<?php
$targetFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/storage/app/public';
$linkFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/public/storage';
symlink($targetFolder,$linkFolder);
echo 'Symlink completed';
```

4. Go to web site example.com/mysymlink.php

Answer (score 3):

Using Laravel in shared hosting environment probably not the best decision. Some many good options are now available for the same price and you just need to put a bit of effort to understand how to work with them, even if you have no prior experience. You can use **DigitalOcean**, **Linode**, **Vultr** or many more and it will save you a ton of time.

In case you for some reason still want to use shared hosting and to actually answer your question you can

- Investigate  to set a right symlink (This possibility nowadays exist almost everywhere) it should be something like `ln -s /home/user/laravel/storage/app/public /home/user/public_html/storage`. *Of course it should by your path which can be different depending of your hosting structure, you should be able to figure out it yourself.*
- Try to implement in some workaround way. For example you can try to put files from `storage` to `storage/app/public` folder manually (you even can latter automate it by using some script). But workarounds product new workarounds, better not do it hard and wrong way but instead use simple and right even if it seems hard for you at first glance.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using Storage facade, you can use custom method to upload file to your public directory

```
if($request->has('image')){
        $img = $request->file('image');
        $ext = $img->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $name = time().'.'.$ext;
        $path = public_path('\img\uploads');
        $img->move($path, $name);
        User::where('id', $user->id)->update([
            'image' => $name
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: **-You can solve it in another way to create a symlinkexample.php file into your public folder and run the file path into browser.**
**-Then Storage folder will be created into public folder. Folder path will be public/storage with linked to your public folder.** 
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
_**Example**_

`<?php
    $targetFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/storage/app/public';
    $linkFolder = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/public/storage';
    symlink($targetFolder,$linkFolder);
    echo 'Symlink process successfully completed';
?>`