# How to link public storage without ssh access or cron jobs?

Tags: laravel, ssh, deployment, laravel-artisan, shared-hosting

I need to deploy a laravel app, which uses the `storage` folder as `public storage` but I don't have `ssh access`. I'm trying to find a substitute for:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

I've found this thread: [Generating a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56661584/laravel-storage-link-in-shared-hosting) by putting this route into `web.php`:

`Route::get('generate', function (){ \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::call('storage:link'); echo 'ok'; });`

But it didn't solve the problem. Am I doing it wrong? How do I link public storage?

Edit: The shitty server I'm trying to deploy to doesn't offer cron jobs.

Comment: what did it do though? When calling the URL `http://example.com/generate` what happens? Nothing? Error?  (example.com here is your website)

Comment: Everything works except that the website can't load the images, that are in the public storage. So they show the broken icon.

Comment: So there are no errors running the command? Check the logs in case there's anything that pops up in there

Comment: For every image, that can't be loaded the console shows `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: **are there any errors when running the route you just created?**

Comment: @apokryfos No, neither the console nor laravel log show errors regarding the route.

Comment: @apokryfos I think I found the problem. The supposed link file inside public folder shows the wrong path. Instead of showing the server link path, it shows my local machine's link path. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Make sure you've not uploaded any config cache and check if you have the correct .env file uploaded

Answer (score 3):

create a corn job if available and after the job run the first time. delete this

```
ln -s /home/user/laravel/storage/app/public /home/user/public_html/storage
```

Comment: I just noticed that the shitty server doesn't even offer cron jobs. Thank you for your answer but is there another way?

Comment: I've edited the question, to not have to create a new post. Sorry, it invalidates your answer. Nonetheless you have helped me!

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I didn't understand how to use the storage link route correctly. I had to add:

```
Route::get('/linkstorage', function (){
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::call('storage:link');
    echo 'storage linked!';
});
```

to `web.php` and actually navigate to `domain-name/linkstorage` to trigger the `artisan call`. After that the storage was linked and everything worked.