# Problem reading and displaying images in a Laravel project on hosting

Tags: laravel

Could you please advise about a problem in laravel project?
The laravel project is built with livewire
The project includes uploading images of more than one Model
It works fine on localhost
But when uploading the project to hosting, the images are not read
I know the problem is solved in localhost by the command
php artisan storage:link
But on hosting the folder is ignored
Because one of the main folders for any project is the storage folder
So what is the correct way to solve this problem

I tried the code

```
    Route::get('/storage', function () {
       Artisan::call('storage:link');
    });
```

But I ran into a problem

Forbidden

> You don't have permission to access this resource.

note:
The way to publish the folders I use is to put all the project folders in the public_html folder with a change after the lines in the index.php file
For information, the files are uploaded correctly, and the files are definitely on the hosting, but they do not appear on the site or on the control panel
Please advise those who have experience in uploading photos and uploading projects to hosting.

The laravel project is built with livewire
The project includes uploading photos
It works fine on localhost
But when uploading the project to hosting, the images are not displayed

Comment: You need to have access to a terminal (SSH), else you are basically done, Laravel will not work correctly and you will have a lot of issues just because you are not using a dedicated virtual machine like EC2 (AWS) or a Droplet (DigitalOcean)

Comment: Do you mean that if I can open the terminal command editor on the hosting, then if I can type the line (php artisan storage: link) it will still work properly on uploading images

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel storage link in shared hosting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56661584/laravel-storage-link-in-shared-hosting)